# c++ declaring and testing variable in while condition

Tags: c++

In the following piece of code, the flow of execution never enters the while
condition and ndx1 is always 0, what is the reason?

```
while( int ndx1 = 10 && (ndx1 > 0)   )
{
    // some statements
    ndx1--;
}
```

Comment: Do you compile with warnings?

Comment: int ndx1 = 0 is not a condition.

Comment: what do you expect the code to do? If you write `ndx1=10` you get `ndx1` assigned with `10`...

Comment: Yes, but there are no warnings

Comment: `int ndx1 = 10 && (ndx1 > 0)` is (likely) invariant, hence useless. Also the `ndx1` in `(ndx1 > 0)` is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement

```
while( int ndx1 = 10 && (ndx1 > 0)   )
```

is equivalent to

```
while( int ndx1 = ( 10 && (ndx1 > 0) )   )
```

That is expression (the initializer used in the declaration of `ndx1`)

```
( 10 && (ndx1 > 0) )
```

uses uninitialized variabel `ndx1` itself that has indeterminate value. As result the program behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Hi Vlad, I was trying to figure out the issue with the while-loop. I was not looking for another for-loop solution. Thanks for your explanation!. It would be great if you could edit out the for-loops.

Comment: @knn What do you mean? Do the for loops hamper the answer?

Comment: @knn O;k I approved your changes.:)

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
while( int ndx1 = 10 && (ndx1 > 0)   )
```

is interpreted as:

```
while( int ndx1 = (10 && (ndx1 > 0))   )
```

That is subject to undefined behavior since `ndx1` is used before being initialized.

A `for` loop will be better for your needs.

```
for( int ndx1 = 10; ndx1 > 0; --ndx1  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Short-circuiting AND (`&&`) has higher precedence than assignment (`=`), thus you're assigning `ndx1` to the expression `10 && (ndx1 > 0)`, which contains `ndx1`. This is undefined behavior, since `ndx1` has not yet been initialized on the first iteration. By happenstance, it is likely to be zero on the first iteration, thus `10 && (ndx1 > 0)` evaluates to false, which is assigned to `ndx1`, and the while condition fails, thus the loop is never entered.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence.

Comment: There is no an assignment. It is a declaration of a variable with an expression used as an initializer.

Comment: Hmm, I think you may be right. But the same precedence rules apply, no?

Comment: In case of a declaration it is not an assignment operator, It does not take part in the expression in the right side.